# wordpress + slack

Tags: wordpress, slack

Можно ли и как подключить slack к wordpress??

Или какие плагины можно подключить для групповых чатов по типу slack

Answer (score 0):

У Zapier есть набор интеграций wordpress-slack

https://zapier.com/apps/slack/integrations/wordpress

В бесплатном тарифе можно сделать два запа и до 100 задач ежемесячно

Comment: Чат в админке можно сделать?

Comment: @threedog по ссылке полный список интеграций